# Run multiple function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program for Raspberry Pi that is utilizing multiple function in classes. I have one class that is dedicated to determining when a capacitive touch sensor is clicked and another one class dedicated to determining the weight from HX711 chip. I want to automatize all: when click the capacitive sensor the cell start the weight scale and then, when I click the capacitive sensor for the second times the system call the function cleanAndExit() but I don't know how I can do this stuff.

```
import time
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from hx711 import HX711
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

padPin = 21
GPIO.setup(padPin, GPIO.IN)


class WeightScale:

    def cleanAndExit(self):
        print "Clean GPIO..."
        GPIO.cleanup()
        print "Complete!"
        sys.exit()


    def cliccato(self):
            hx = HX711(5, 6)
            hx.set_reading_format("LSB", "MSB")
            hx.reset()
            hx.tare()
            hx.set_reference_unit(-421)
            while True: 
                time.sleep(0.1)
                n = 100 

 //Run for max 100 seconds and create an array with the last value from weight scale sensor

                for i in range (1, n):
                    val = max(0, int (hx.get_weight(5)))
                    add = []
                    hx.power_down()
                        hx.power_up()
                        time.sleep(0.6)
                    add.append(val)
                    add1 = []
                    add1.append(add[-1:])
                    print add1
                    time.sleep(1)



class TouchSensor:      

    def click(self):
        alreadyPressed = False  
        while True:
            padPressed =  GPIO.input(padPin)
            if padPressed and not alreadyPressed:
                print "click"
                time.sleep(2)





c=WeightScale()
t=TouchSensor()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order you to correctly create a class, you need to define an **init** method with in the class definition. So for example:

```
class TouchSensor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.padPin = 21

    def click(self):
        alreadyPressed = False  
        while True:
            padPressed =  GPIO.input(padPin)
            if padPressed and not alreadyPressed:
                print "click"
                time.sleep(2)
```

Then once you create your object of that class, it is initialized with padPin = 21. Then you use the methods within each class to perform what you're calling 'functions.'

```
t = TouchSensor()
t.click()
```

Try making adjustments and post whatever errors you end up with!

Comment: Made some changes to my code, please let me know your answer

Comment: You're on the right track, but you also need an __init__ method for your other class definition. Additionally, you would probably be perfectly fine without using the multiprocessing library unless that's something you really want to do. 

What error messages are you getting from this?

Answer (score 0):

I make some adjustments to my code:

```
   import time
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from hx711 import HX711
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

padPin = 21
GPIO.setup(padPin, GPIO.IN)


class WeightScale:

    def cleanAndExit(self):
            print ("Clean GPIO...")
            GPIO.cleanup()
            print ("Complete!")
            sys.exit()

    def pesatura(self):
         hx = HX711(5, 6)
         hx.set_reading_format("LSB", "MSB")
         hx.reset()
         hx.tare()
         hx.set_reference_unit(-421)
         while t.status==True: 
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    n = 100
                    for i in range (1, n):
                         val = max(0, int (hx.get_weight(5)))
                         add = []
                         hx.power_down()
                         hx.power_up()
                         time.sleep(0.6)
                         add.append(val)
                         add1 = []
                         add1.append(add[-1:])
                         print (add1)
                         time.sleep(1)
        cleanAndExit()



class TouchSensor:

    def __init__(self):
        self.status = False


    def changeStatus(self):
        if self.status == False:
            self.status = True
            print (self.status)
        else:
            self.status = False
            print (self.status)            

    def click(self):  
        while True:
            padPressed =  GPIO.input(padPin)
            if padPressed:        
                print ("click")
                t.changeStatus()


            alreadyPressed = padPressed
            time.sleep(0.5)






c=WeightScale()
t = TouchSensor()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process (target = t.click())
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process (target = c.pesatura())
    p2.start()
```

I have added a multiprocessing function and method changeStatus for the button click,I want to use it to start the loop of pesatura(self) when self.status==True and after, when self.Status== False (another click) start  cleanAndExit(). But when I start the script it gives me the error ''cleanAndExit() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)''.